# Pandas DataFrame with categoricals fails comparison

Tags: python, pandas

Comparing a dataframe without a categorical column:

```
In[1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[4,2,9],[3,8,2],[2,1,6]], columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])

In[2]: df
Out[1]: 
   one  two  three
0    4    2      9
1    3    8      2
2    2    1      6
In[3]: df == 2
Out[2]: 
     one    two  three
0  False   True  False
1  False  False   True
2   True  False  False
```

Shouldn't this also work if df has categoricals?

```
In[4]: df['two'] = df['two'].astype('category')
df == 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
<snip>
ValueError: Wrong number of dimensions
```

After all, comparing just the Series works:

```
In[5]: df['two'] == 2
Out[3]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: two, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the DataFrame method apply, it applies a function to all the elements of the frame. The following line works when the variable is categorical:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x==2)
```

As to why that particular `ValueError` is thrown, I don't have an answer.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of that workaround. I'll accept your answer in a few days if nothing else comes up that explains the ValueError.

Comment: Any idea how to work around the same error when doing df[df==2] = -2 ? The apply version df[df.apply(lambda x: x==2)] fails with another ValueError.

Comment: And sure enough, I found the workaround myself: df.applymap(lambda x: -2 if x==2 else x)